# Using a non-primeface icon to a p-fileUpload button?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have been trying to replace the icon of the upload button (which is a p-fileupload element) with an icon from FontAwesome (like `fas fa-file-import`) but it keeps showing a blank space instead of the wanted icon.

Here's is the code I have written:

```
<p-fileUpload
  mode="basic"
  [maxFileSize]="10000000"
  chooseLabel="{{ 'ImportBtn' | localize }}"
  class="p-mr-2 p-d-inline-block mr-2"
  chooseIcon="fas fa-file-import"
  accept=".xlsx,.xls"
  customUpload="true"
  [auto]="true"
  (uploadHandler)="uploadBillExcels($event)"
  draggable="true">
</p-fileUpload>
```

Comment: That means FA is not registered properly in the application.